# Delphi (-XE) : casting to a record type with implicit conversion

Tags: delphi, casting, delphi-xe, record, implicit

I have a record type with methods, representing an specific hardware measurement type, read from the instrument as a string. The record contains implicit coversion to (and from) a string. If I cast a string as a record type, it seems to work, but is this safe? That is, does casting a string to a record with implicit string conversion call the implicit conversion as per assigning a temporary value?

```
var  a: MeasurementRecord;         // record type with implicit string conversion & decode methods
b: string;
c:double;
begin
b := Edit1.Text;              // Or any other string source 
a:=b;                         //Ok
a:= edit1.text;               //Ok
c:= a.returnQc;                 // returns measurement quality value

c:= MeasurementRecord(Edit1.text).returnQC;   //Avoiding local variable. This works, but is it correct useage?

end;
```

Comment: how about the declaration of the record?

Comment: @HMcG you really should show us the complete record, hehehe ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly safe. The code `MeasurementRecord(Edit1.text)` will create a `MeasurementRecord` record from the string `Edit1.Text` using your

```
class operator Implicit(S: string): MeasurementRecord
```

and then call the function `returnQC` in it. (However, if you also have a

```
class operator Explicit(S: string): MeasurementRecord
```

then this will be used instead since the cast is actually explicit.)

Comment: that looks like explicit to me. Does that fall back to implicit if explicit is not available?

Comment: @David: Yes, that is exactly what it does. I just added a clarification on that point.

Comment: Thanks for explaining things. I was not aware of the Explicit / Implicit fallback.