# How to use ToString() implicitly in Delphi objects or strings?

Tags: java, delphi

Delphi is like an England Queen Guard. It does not like ambiguity and may even kill to protect the hard code. But Java is almost a street corner woman. When I use this is java:

```
 Button button = new Button();
 String a = "This is a " + button;
```

I get `This is a button`

But if I do that in Delphi:

```
 ShowMessage('This is a ' + Button1);
```

I get an error, because Delphi has `toString()` method (now) but it does not implicitly calls it. Because literal strings are not objects in OP. The correct use is:

```
 ShowMessage('This is a ' + Button1.toString());
```

Is there any way to override this behave so it works like Java?

For reference: [How an object will call toString method implicitly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17051481/how-an-object-will-call-tostring-method-implicitly)

Comment: I don't think that's possible even in the last version of delphi, you can do something similar with "records" and operators, using "class operator" on "records", despite the "class" keyword, see http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Operator_Overloading_(Delphi) for more information.

Comment: not sure if I should +1 or -1 you for calling Java a whore.

Comment: The default toString() implementation in Java will not give the object (variable) name, it will return something like someObjectClassname@hashcodenumber - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712139

Comment: Yes, like in Delphi, it was made so class creators create their own implementation of `toString()` to return something more substantial to the new class, like returning a date when you create a date handler class.

Comment: If it's no more adequate than creating a `GetDate()` I can't tell. Depends on the developer's will.

Comment: Note that in Java this feature is not limited to objects. Since Java's first version, string concatenation also works with primitive types.

Comment: @MK that's why everybody wants "her" ;-)

Comment: I think you may try to implement some interface or record with implicit typecasts. Then it would go like `IMyString := 'This is a '; IMyString := IMyString + Button1;`

Comment: @mjn does it ? or is it really implicit boxing and ocncatenation of objects and not of primitive types ?  I bill that this whole question was made out of last Allen Bauer blog post about ARC and Delphi future directions.

Comment: @Arioch'The you mean like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666786/delphi-xe-casting-to-a-record-type-with-implicit-conversion ? He should at least show to us the declaration of that record he mentioned. Can you reproduce in an answer here?

Comment: @EASI like that or like recently mentioned Andreas' `IWeakPtr<TObject>` hack.

Comment: damn! i meant flattered, not flattened! jeez...

Comment: The question now is: is it a good idea to insert class operators in the TObject class definition so it would work like Java?

Comment: @Arioch'The no, Autoboxing is a feature which was introduced in Java 5 (eight years later)

Comment: Cool. People I know that are Java evangelizers and Delphi crucifyiers  would never accept that truth. :-P

Comment: @EASI I am confused: which thruth?

Comment: That many Java features are in Delphi even before, but developers just don't use them, because they're too unstable and hard to do maintenance. IMHO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way to enforce an implicit cast or method call on an object instance.

If this was a record that you controlled then you could implement an `Implicit` class operator that would perform a cast to `string`.

The issue discussed link that you refer to is simply an implementation detail of `PrintStream.println()`. That relies on the ability of `String.valueOf()` to come up with a string representation for any object which in turn relies on `Object.toString()`. In fact the discussion there concerning `println()` is unrelated to the way the `+` operator in Java works which is the pertinent issue in your question.

Delphi's `TObject` has a virtual `ToString` method that could be used to perform the same purpose. So it would be easy enough to use the exact same technique as `PrintStream.println()` in Delphi code.

Comment: Could you please cast an example of an Implicit class operator in order to enrich your answer?  ;-}

Comment: Sorry, an example of what?

Comment: Do you happen to know which (non-.Net) version of Delphi introduced `TObject.ToString`?

Comment: @Rob According to Marco it was D2009: http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/6hidden_delphi2009.html

Answer (score 4):

If you had a special function that worked like `Format`, you could get that behavior. I wrote [a function like that](https://gist.github.com/rkennedy/4566675) several years ago, back when the built-in function didn't support Unicode. I've now updated it to support calling `ToString` on an object when it's passed as the argument for the `%s` format string. You'd call it like this:

```
ShowMessage(WideFormat('This is a %s', [Button1]));
```

I'm sorry the code hasn't really been touched in several years, so it might not work as-is in newer Delphi versions. You'll have to decide whether it's worth the effort to update that code, although it was included in Project Jedi long enough that it did get a few nominal updates to support `UnicodeString` and 64-bit compilation.

Comment: Thank you. I'm afraid I can't really vouch for its quality anymore, though, since the last version of Delphi I had was Delphi 2005. Someone should update the code to account for UnicodeString as the native data type instead of just an argument type, but I'm not sure I'm the one to do it. It's all on GitHub, though, so anyone feeling so inspired can fork it or send me a pull request.

Comment: I second @EASI the code was pleasure to read:) But wait.. your last Delphi version was Delphi 2005..does it mean you are not coding in Delphi/Pascal anymore?:(

Comment: I haven't used Delphi since 2007, @Wodzu (except for a few minutes last weekend helping my dad debug a hanging program in Delphi 5). I haven't used Delphi professionally since 2005.

Comment: Not really, @David. I had a test project I used during development. Mostly just one call to the function, and I'd change the argument list for each case I wished to test. This was close to 10 years ago; I'd never heard of unit tests at the time.

Comment: That makes porting to Unicode Delphi a little less appealing.

Answer (score 2):

Too bad that it works only on ARM compiler and Delphi.NET 
Great article by Nick Hodges in http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/34324

```
TMyClass = class
    class operator Add(a, b: TMyClass): TMyClass; // Addition of two operands of type TMyClass
    class operator Subtract(a, b: TMyClass): TMyclass; // Subtraction of type TMyClass
    class operator Implicit(a: Integer): TMyClass; // Implicit conversion of an Integer to type TMyClass
    class operator Implicit(a: TMyClass): Integer; // Implicit conversion of TMyClass to Integer
    class operator Explicit(a: Double): TMyClass; // Explicit conversion of a Double to TMyClass
end;

// Example implementation of Add class operator 
TMyClass.Add(a, b: TMyClass): TMyClass;
begin
  ...
end;

var
x, y: TMyClass
begin
  x := 12; // Implicit conversion from an Integer 
  y := x + x; // Calls TMyClass.Add(a, b: TMyClass): TMyClass 
  b := b + 100; // Calls TMyClass.Add(b, TMyClass.Implicit(100)) 
end;
```

Comment: Also, it only works on Delphi.net and the new mobile compilers. For the desktop Delphi compiler operator overloading is for records only.

Comment: Greetings from 2013 to future readers. If it's 2015 this is probably the best answer.